# How do we optimize performance when using multiple instances of a Lottie animation?

Tags: react-native, lottie

We are facing huge FPS drops when we display multiple instances of a Lottie animation using [lottie-react-native.](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-react-native)

To replicate this, try to display 6-7 instances of the following animation, you can see that FPS drops to around 4-5 on both JS and UI threads.

Link to animation file: https://www.lottiefiles.com/236-accept-arrows

What can be done to prevent FPS drops?